# Missing Web Files When Deploying EAR Using Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, jboss7.x

I am currently upgrading my web app running on Java 6 and JBoss EAP 5.2 using STS 2.9 to Java 7 and JBoss EAP 6.2 using Eclipse Luna.

I have noticed that when I deployed my EAR file via manually dragging file or adding the file in the server tab the CLASS, LIB and other custom folders are not included in the exploded folder in JBoss directory.

I am not sure if this problem belongs to Eclipse or JBoss.

Any suggestions would be a great help.